# PHPEXCEL ошибка импорта в бд

Tags: php

Имеется такой вот код PHPEXCEL с последующим занесением в бд, он почему-то не выполняется

```
<?php
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("parser",$db);
$html = file_get_html("http://localhost");
foreach($html->find("tr") as $row) {
    $td = $row->find("td");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tableasd`(`title`, `articul`, `category`) VALUES ({$td[1]},{$td[2]},{$td[3]})");
}
?>
```

VAR_DUMP запроса выдает NULL как заставить этот скрипт работать?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку нашел, изменил код. В конечном итоге код выглядит вот так. Парсер работает.

```
<?php
require_once("simple_html_dom.php");
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("parser",$db);
$html = file_get_html("http://localhost");
foreach($html->find("tr") as $row) {
    $td = $row->find("td");
    $category = $td[1];
    $title = $td[2];
    $articul = $td[3];
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tableasd`(`title`, `articul`, `category`) VALUES ('{$title}','{$articul}','{$category}')");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

я как минимум не вижу кавычек в запросе, которые обрамляют все {$td[...]}. И вообще перебирайтесь на mysqli, там будут placeholder.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'parser');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `tableasd`(`title`, `articul`, `category`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $td[1],$td[2],$td[3]);
```

первый параметр для bind - тип переменной.
i   соответствующая переменная имеет тип integer
d   соответствующая переменная имеет тип double
s   соответствующая переменная имеет тип string
b   соответствующая переменная является большим двоичным объектом (blob) и будет пересылаться пакетами

Comment: Код поправил, запрос все равно не проходит. Как внутри цикла, так и вне него.

Comment: $q = "INSERT INTO ..."; echo $q; что выведет?

Comment: string запроса.

Comment: 1. точно находит $td? echo $td[0]; 2. Запрос точно валидный? Если вставить его в тот же phpmyadmin, вставка происходит?

Comment: Да, запрос обрабатывается.